# How to Wire Freshair UV Light Dual Lamp Kit in HVAC

Tags: electrical, hvac

I bought a Fresh-Aire AHU Series TUV-200D-1 Dual Lamp UV System kit I want to install in my HVAC system. Installing the UV lamp and ballast is straight forward but I don't know how to hook up the electrical connection.   Is this something I can do or should I hire a electrician?

Below is what my HVAC wiring looks like and the kit I bought:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do the instructions with the light say to do?

Comment: Hi Freeman, I adding a picture of the wiring diagram from the manual.  There are only 3 wires on the kit which has a Black, White and Green wire.

Comment: the diagram also shows only one set of black, white and green wires

Comment: Yes, the kit only has one set of wires which are black, white and green.

Comment: What make and model is your air handler?

Comment: I know the brand is Carrier but I don't know the model name.